# Why does nginx require default ssl server to have a certificate?

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a testing site with 2 domains and I want to enable SSL for both.

Also, I want to have a default server to display an error page if a client is accessing some page out of those 2 domains.

This is my `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name a.com;
    ssl_certificate a.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key a.key;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name b.com;
    ssl_certificate b.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key b.key;
}
server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    ...
}
```

Problem: The default server must have a valid cert/key pair, **even if the client is connecting to `a.com` or `b.com`**.

If I don't specify a cert/key pair on the default ssl server, nginx gives me this error:

> no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking

I don't understand the logic here. With SNI enabled, when a client clearly says it's accessing `a.com`, which has a standalone server block in `nginx.conf`, why does nginx still require the default server to have a cert/key pair? Why does it even bother with the default server?

Comment: I tried to answer your question but after replying and re-reading my answer, I doubted about what you were really asking. Are you asking why you need to define a certificate/key for a server block or why do you need a default_server?

Comment: nginx requires it because https requires it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Even if there's SNI and the default server is not expected to be accessed?

Comment: There is always something accessing the default server, even if it's just malicious bots.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I understand some clients will access the default server. But the problem is the default server still needs a certificate when clients access other named servers (`a.com`)

Comment: The default server needs a certificate, full stop. It doesn't matter what clients do.

Comment: @MichaelHampton If so then nginx should report config error when you start it if there's no cert in the default server. But there's no error at start time at all. The error happens when a client tries to connect to another server which has its own cert. In this case nginx shouldn't do anything with default server because the request should be routed to the server being accessed. I suppose this is a bug.

Comment: Oh, I agree it should be a config error that nginx refuses to start with. But that's something for the nginx developers to fix, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [ssl_reject_handshake](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_reject_handshake) for the default server on 443. That way you don’t need a certificate, and there won’t be an “untrusted site” warning on the end users computer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

@MrA1Sauce has the right idea with

[`ssl_reject_handshake on;`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_reject_handshake)

The problem is the following... if you are doing virtual hosting in nginx (multiple domain names with different SSL certs on same IP address), nginx relies on the Server Name Indication ("SNI") TLS extension to get a hint about which hostname will be requested so it can select the appropriate "virtual host" server block (and corresponding SSL Certificate) to use when establishing the TLS session before HTTP requests can happen.

HTTPS doesn't work with virtual hosting (one IP, multiple certs) for web clients that don't support SNI because without SNI the webserver doesn't know which of multiple SSL certificates to respond with. Fortunately only Windows XP, old java and old android are the only "recent" clients that don't support SNI.  Their market share is small enough to ignore unless you have a very special use case with a legacy client base (in which case you can look at using a single SAN certificate to cover multiple names).

Even with SNI, people may reach your nginx server under a different name (anyone can point their domain name at your IP) or directly via the server's IP address.  In those cases, there is no matching server block, so which certificate should nginx return?

When there is no matching `server_name` for the inbound request, nginx defaults to first alphabetical `server_name` that can handle the current request (port number).  If you specify a default_server, nginx will use that instead assuming the default server handles that port (e.g. HTTPS/443 for SSL case).  So if you don't want one of your non-default virtual servers handling unknown requests...your default server must support HTTPS/443.

Normally this requires specifying an SSL cert/key...but what cert/key should you use for a default server that might get requests from random names or directly on the IP address?

Using [`ssl_reject_handshake on;`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_reject_handshake) in the default server causes nginx to just "hang up" on these requests (unknown server names) and removes the requirement for you to specify some cert/key in the default server.

A technique we did in the past was to have a long-lived self-signed wildcard (`*`) cert on the default server so we would have a chance to show an error page (if the user bypassed the warnings to continue to the site).  However most browsers will block this and end users should not be encouraged to install/trust your self-signed wildcard cert (security issue).  Plus if you have any security audit/scanners, they will likely flag this self-signed cert as a problem.

But the main thing we were trying to accomplish was to avoid that one of our real virtual hosts/domains are being served as the default under unknown names when no other match was found.  As I said before...this happens if you don't specify a default_server that handles https.

Setting `ssl_reject_handshake on;` in the default https/443 server block allows us to avoid specifying certificate/key in the default_server block at all and ensures that the user won't get the wrong webpage with a certificate error and will instead just get an TLS Handshake refused error if they try to connect to the webserver via IP or an unknown name.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_reject_handshake on;
    
    # breaks https for non-SNI clients
}
```

## Aside: dealing with non-SNI legacy devices

If you want to host multiple names on same IP and support non-SNI clients...look into getting a SAN ("Subject Alternative Name") certificate.  This allows a single certificate/key (single server block) for all names that that SAN certificate covers.  Basically a multi-domain certificate.  So nginx doesn't have to decide which certificate to return and can always return the SAN cert whether or not the client device supports SNI.

LetsEncrypt does support SAN certs, so once you get it setup it isn't that bad to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a testing site with 2 domains. I want to enable SSL for both
>   and have a default SSL server handling errors (display an error page
>   when clients specify incorrect domain name):
>
> [...]
>
> But I don't understand the logic here. Why does nginx bother with the
>   default server if the client has clearly specified which domain it
>   wants?

**The certificate is mandatory for the ssl servers**, if there was no certificate, what's the point? HTTPS wouldn't work.

You must define the ssl certificate and key, inside or outside the server block. If you define a "**default_server**", but you are not defining a domain, then it will always display a warning that the domain doesn't match the certificate (unless you are using wildcard certificates or some other specific use cases).

When you define [name-based HTTPS servers](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html), you have to keep in mind the following, from the official docs:

> With this configuration a browser receives the default server’s
>   certificate, i.e. www.example.com regardless of the requested server
>   name. This is caused by SSL protocol behaviour. The SSL connection is
>   established before the browser sends an HTTP request and nginx does
>   not know the name of the requested server. Therefore, it may only
>   offer the default server’s certificate.

As you found out, a self-signed certificate accomplishes this and will allow you to present a webpage or redirect in a default_server in case there was no match for any other of the defined **server_name** blocks, although it (might, depending on configuration) present a warning.

If your question is why you need to define a **default_server**, you don't. If you don't specify a default_server block, it will use the first by alphabetical order, if someone reached your server with an unknown domain name (usually won't happen), or present the corresponding **server_name**.

**Update**

Extending my answer in response to your comment:

> The quoted part is what i'm asking. Why does nginx serve the default
>   server's certificate with SNI enabled (keep reading on that page
>   Server Name Indication)

Check my last paragraph above, that's how virtual hosts (or server blocks in nginx terminology) and the **default_server** work. Nginx will serve the **default_server** block if you define one in a **server block** and the **server_name** doesn't match the request in the other blocks. You can define a **server block** with a **default_server** *to force a catch-all* to that specific block, otherwise, nginx will default to the first server block (either in nginx.conf or in sites-enabled/conf.d if included). Either you define it or nginx will choose the first block for that purpose, but a server block will be the default.

It won't serve it **unless** someone reaches your server with an **undefined server_name**, following your example, let's say someone pointed "c.com" to the IP of your nginx, then the default_server will catch that request and present whatever you defined.

Comment: The quoted part is what i'm asking. Why does nginx serve the default server's certificate with SNI enabled (keep reading on that page Server Name Indication)

Comment: Updated my answer due to comment's extension limit. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: The puzzle is, that ssl certificate seems necessary even if you access a.com. i'm not expecting this access has anything to do with the default server when sni is enabled.

Comment: @Cyker I believe you are making an invalid assumption about how SNI works for with Nginx. Nginx only looks at the `host` header to determine which server name to route the request through. If none is found it will use the default server, or the first server block. The HTTP handshake containing the server name (SNI) happens before the 'host' header is sent, and is therefore not used by Nginx to determine which server route to select. SNI in the handshake will help determine which cert to use if you have multiple domain certs in the same file in your HTTP block.